# Error in Deploy webservice FTP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ftp

Im trying to download files that are inside the FTP server with webservice.

```asp
[WebMethod]
    public string BrowseFileSimplify(string FileName, string varlocaldirectory)
    {

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z_-]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}$");
        Match match = regex.Match(FileName);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            try
            {


                string inputfilepath = varlocaldirectory + "\\" + FileName;

                using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
                {
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                    byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(uri+FileName);

                    using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath))
                    {
                        file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                        file.Close();
                    }
                    return "Download Success";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Problem with " + ex.Message; //Error en la aplicacion
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error with file format"; //Error en el formato del archivo
        }

    }
```

It works fine when i execute with VisualStudio, it returns **"Download Success"**, but when i upload to [web](http://cport93-001-site1.btempurl.com/wsFTP.asmx) it return:**"Error: Unable to connect to the remote server"**

I need put some code into web.config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its likely a networking issue.  Would need to know more about the hosting environment to be sure.  You would usually start troubleshooting by logging into the server and trying to ping/telnet to the target ftp server and go from there.

Comment: It was the host, i tried with another host like azure and it worked. Thanks.